# Index assignment problem for memory game in Python

Tags: python, list, variable-assignment

I have a memory game which I have implemented using states, using a list of 16 cards;
state 0 equates to the first card being clicked on, revealed and saving its index to a variable `card 1` , state 1 flips the second card clicked on and saves it to `card2`. Finally, state 3 checks if the first and second cards match, if not unflips (assigns a `False`  value) them and moves back to state 1.

My code works from state 0 and state 1, both card1 and card2 indices are saved correctly. Upon moving on to state 3 the values of card1 and card2 change to the card1 value, which is erroneous.

The code:

```
def mouseclick(pos):
    # add game state logic here
    global state , exposed, cards
    card1 = 0
    card2 = 0
    current_card = 0
    
    index = pos[0] // 50
    
    if state == 0:
        card1 = index
        exposed[card1] = True
        state = 1
        print(card1)

    elif state == 1:
        if exposed[index] == False:
            card2 = index
            exposed[card2] = True
            state = 2
            print(card2)
            
    elif state == 2:
        print(cards[card1], cards[card2])
        print(card1, card2)
        if exposed[index] == False:
            exposed[index] = True
            if cards[card1] == cards[card2]:
                exposed[card1] = True
                exposed[card2] = True
            else:
                exposed[card1] = False
                exposed[card2] = False
            card1 = index
            exposed[card1] = True
            state = 1
            print(exposed)
```

the exposed list is a range of 16 False values where False corresponds to unflipped (not shown) and True is flipped (shown).
cards is a list of shuffled cards (1 to 8 + 1 to 8).
example output based on the print statements is:

```
0
1
4 4
0 0
[True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

The cards at index 0 and 1 do not match so should be False values in the `exposed` list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, through toil managed to fix this through making the card1 and card2 variables global. Don't know how/why this worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).